# Velocity in Uniform Circular Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, centripetal-force

In Uniform circular motion, the force is perpendicular to the direction of velocity so it doesn't change its speed along the tangential direction, but won't it cause an acceleration along the radial direction and increase its speed along the radial direction causing an overall change in its speed.

Comment: Hi. Your question is?

Comment: The question is why is it only changing the direction of velocity and not changing the magnitude of it.

Comment: Welcome to PSE and Newtonian Mechanics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question may be divided into two parts:

1. > OP: "In Uniform circular motion, the force is perpendicular to the direction of velocity so it doesn't change its speed along the tangential direction, but won't it cause an acceleration along the radial direction"

According to Newton's First Law,

> In an inertial frame of reference, an object either remains at rest or continues to move at a constant velocity, unless acted upon by a force

Note that the law states that force causes change in velocity and not speed. This is important because speed and velocity are not same.
Also note that the definition of acceleration is the rate of change of the velocity of an object with respect to time.

Thus the presence of a (centripetal) force does cause an acceleration of the particle, which changes its velocity. At each moment, the force causes the particle to change its direction. Since velocity is a vector quantity, a change in direction too would be considered as change in velocity, which is by definition, acceleration. The direction of acceleration of the particle is towards the centre. The magnitude of velocity however, is always constant in uniform circular motion.

2. > OP: "and increase its speed along the radial direction causing an overall change in its speed."

When you want to increase the velocity of a particle, you have to increase it's kinetic energy.

According to work-energy theorem,

> For any net force acting on a particle moving along any curvilinear path, it can be demonstrated that its work equals the change in the kinetic energy of the particle

$W=\int\vec{F}\cdot \vec{d\mathbf{r}}=K_f-K_i$

Since the centripetal force is always perpendicular to the motion of the particle, work done by the force is $0$.

So,

$K_f-K_i=0$
$\Rightarrow K_f=K_i$

This means that the kinetic energy of the particle does not change due to a force acting perpendicular to its direction of motion.

Answer (score 1):

Most of us often not able to visualize the acceleration caused by a change in direction of the velocity vector. Consider the particle doing a uniform circular motion, so that it's velocity vector is changing. Something like this:

[image]

Now the elementary calculation for acceleration can be found in any text on mechanics. I'm writing the expression directly.

$$\mathbf{a}=(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2)\hat{r}+(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta})\hat{\theta}$$

For uniform circular motion, $\dot{r}=0,\ddot{r}=0$ and $\ddot{\theta}=0$.
$$\mathbf{a}=-R\dot{\theta}^2\hat{r}$$

So to set a particle in circular motion, you need apply a force that balances this inward radial force (called centripetal force).

For example suppose a string whose one end is joint with a bob and other is fixed at point. In this case the tension provides centripetal force for the circular motion.

Or consider a death well where a bike rider goes around doing circular motion. Here centripetal force provide by normal force.

Summary: In a circular motion you have a restriction that $\dot{r}=0$. There is a inward accelertion but that is balanced by other forces.

Answer (score 1):

A radial force applies no torque, therefore it does not affect the angular velocity. When the force is directly radial it may cause spatial translation of the object but will not change its angular velocity.. So, yes, a radial force can alter the velocity of the object without affecting the rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is a vector so it has a magnitude and a direction. In uniform circular motion, the magnitude is constant but the direction is continually changing. Consider this diagram from
[LibreTexts](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map%3A_University_Physics_I_-_Mechanics_Sound_Oscillations_and_Waves_(OpenStax)/04%3A_Motion_in_Two_and_Three_Dimensions/4.05%3A_Uniform_Circular_Motion):

[image: Uniform circular motion]

In a small time interval, $\Delta$t, there is a change in the velocity vector, $\Delta$**v** in the radial direction toward the center C. This change is just the right amount to keep the object moving in a circle. Only the direction changes due to the force toward the center.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the speed (magnitude of the velocity vector), work must be done (by work energy theorem).

Work is defined as $W=\int\vec F\cdot\vec v\space dt$

By definition $\vec F\perp\vec v$

Dot product of any two perpendicular vectors is 0, which means work is zero.

Answer (score 0):

One of the criterion for uniform circular motion is that the centripetal force is:

$$ \vec F = -m\frac{v^2} r \hat r $$

You can show that that leads to:

$$ \dot r = 0 $$

and along with

$$ \ddot \theta = 0$$

you have "uniform" circular motion. Any other magnitude for the centripetal force will lead to:

$$ \dot r \ne 0$$

and the motion will be neither uniform nor circular, to the extent that a spiral isn't circular.